# PayPal Buy Button

Tags: html, paypal

So I'm just trying to setup my website and my main issue is trying to get a button that people can click and it will take people to PayPal to checkout and I'll get the money, but the only problem I have is that the PayPal button that I generate on my PayPal account it is a yellowish orange button that doesn't fit my color scheme, and I have one on my website that I want to use that you will see in the screenshot I provide.
" https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUDR5.jpg " Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your button code, you can always change the image of the button by changing the image source in this line ;

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal â“ The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```